# Why is the DownloadTwitterUserInfo method of IAuthHttpGateway not returning JSON result?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I'm trying to use the `TwitterAuthProvider`, but it seems like the implementation is deprecated since it uses twitter 1.0, I´m getting the following exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone.

It happens after the user auth when it´s time to load the `userInfo` and try to parse the response into json:

```cs
protected override void LoadUserAuthInfo(AuthUserSession userSession, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
{
    ...
    var json = AuthHttpGateway.DownloadTwitterUserInfo(tokens.UserId);
    var objs = JsonObject.ParseArray(json);
    ...
}
```

Download Twitter User Info:

```cs
public const string TwitterUserUrl = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id={0}";
public string DownloadTwitterUserInfo(string twitterUserId)
{
    twitterUserId.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty("twitterUserId");
    var url = TwitterUserUrl.Fmt(twitterUserId);
    var json = url.GetStringFromUrl();
    return json;
}
```

Comment: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json? Is not used any more you need to use open auth to connect to twitter api  now.

Comment: yeah I understand, the problem is that I haven´t seen an update for the twitter auth for SS and a twitter api call using get instead of post